# How to achieve ipfs-pubsub-room reliability

Tags: ipfs

I try to use https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-pubsub-room in my application. And I try to understand some things.

```
const ipfs = new IPFS({
  EXPERIMENTAL: {
    pubsub: true
  },
  config: {
    Addresses: {
      Swarm: [
        '/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star'
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

How I understand I should manually host rendezvous server instead `/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star'` to allow clients communicates each other (chatting). But what if Ip will be blocked (for example by internet provider) or just server down? How I can achieve reliability in that case?

I can't see any "decentralisation" in that case.

Answer (score 0):

So i think the idea is you can use public servers to do the websocket pubsub with the clients... you could also setup a tor hidden service and use one of the public gateways but again all those things can be blocked... You need some way to allow the members of your network to get each others addresses so the new clients can bootstrap into the nodes that are participating.

Comment: im still trying to understand how to use https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/examples/circuit-relaying/README.md so it can proxy through bridge nodes

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to use something like [orbit-db](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db) where instead of trying to have users talk to each other directly. **The chat room state would be managed by a decentralized [CRDT](https://crdt.tech/)**. That would eliminate any potential network hurdles and it would open up the possibility to add even more to the network since now there potentially is a "chat room ledger" that can be consumed.

It was pretty hard for me to understand at first but after doing proper digging it all makes sense. Every user has their own copy of the "database" locally and p2p-websocket-star enables the connectivity to other clients to sync their individual databases.

This means if `A --> B` has connectivity issues. Then `A --> {IPFS to keep OrbitDB Db State} --> B`. No connectivity issues. I have tested latency and its pretty good! With chat, you are not expecting like instant anyway... Give it some thought.